# MySQL get sum for each N element of a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
ID - price - date
1  - 10    - 2017-01-01
2  - 50    - 2017-01-02
3  - 20    - 2017-01-01
4  - 10    - 2017-01-01
5  - 5     - 2017-01-01
6  - 10    - 2017-01-02
7  - 20    - 2017-01-02
8  - 20    - 2017-01-02
```

and I want to get price sum for each 2 element of a distinct date...

In this case, my result must be

```
2017-01-01 -> 30
2017-01-02 -> 60
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT x.date
     , SUM(y.price) 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.date = x.date 
   AND y.id <= x.id 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id -- a functional dependency
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

(Actually, I find it odd that this works, but it seems to)

Comment: I like your query alignment. Which editor do you use?

Comment: @GurV I only use TextPad (for Windows)

Answer (score 2):

One way is using correlated subquery:

```
select
    date,
    (   select sum(price)
        from (
            select price
            from your_table t2
            where t1.date = t2.date
            order by id
            limit 2
        )
    ) total 
from your_table t1
group by date;
```